# Selecting a set number of files using Python

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

I have been able to determine the most recent file from a selected dir using this code:

```
station_dir = os.listdir(station)
station_file = sorted([f for f in station_dir if f.startswith('OD__CAAL')])
new_file1 = station_file[-1]
print new_file1
```

Depending on my needs, how is it possible to print out two or three of the most recent files from the same directory?
Time will vary and files could be new or old.

Comment: most recent files, means last modification time, check `os.path.getmtime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
station_dir = os.listdir(station)
station_file = sorted([f for f in station_dir if f.startswith('OD__CAAL')])
new_files = station_file[-3:]
print new_files[0], new_files[1], new_files[2]
```